# Comparing a string with several different strings

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

I want to compare one string with many strings. How is that done in C#?

Comment: OK, after reading this question several times and also deepasundaris own answer with additional info, i think he wants the following:

I have a list of several strings and need to find a unknown substring that resides in every string within that list

Comment: please re-phrase the question to reflect what you really mean.

Comment: Can you please edit your initial question to provide a bit more information? I noticed that you clarified the problem in some of your comments here, but the best way would be to update the question itself, so that people don't have to dig through all the answers to understand what you need.

Comment: Also, this should be tagged as language-agnostic

Comment: @Yoni,  I disagree!  What is language-agnostic about "logic in c# for that"?

Comment: Hey @Ash, the answer is in the word "logic". Also, I suspect that the essence of the problem deepasundari experiences is not with the specific methods to compare strings in c#, but rather with the algorithm itself. I guess it is a homework assignment ...

Comment: @Yoni, ok, but I think we should wait a bit longer for deepasundari to clarify the question before making changes ourselves.

Comment: You **really** need to stop re-posting this question. If something is unclear, please edit this question to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to check if a string is contained in a list of strings you could use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) extension method:

```
bool isStringContainedInList = 
    new[] { "string1", "string2", "string3" }.Contains("some string")
```

Comment: But the problem is i dono what is "Some String" i want to find that...
how to do that?
to find common among many strings...

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you look at this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) about the **longest common substring problem**.

I recall from undergrad that one strategy to find the longest common substring, you can start by finding a slightly shorter substring and then expand from there (and repeat). That is, if "abcd" is a common substring, then so does "abc" and so does "ab".

This lends to a repeating algorithm where you first find all the 2-letters pairs that appear in your strings (I am not bothering with one letter substrings because for large dataset they'll get include the whole alphabet). Then you iterate again to find all 3-letters substrings, and so on ...

Answer (score 5):

To compare all strings in a collection to each other to find duplicates, it's most efficient to use a Dictionary:

```
string[] strings = { "Zaphod", "Trillian", "Zaphod", "Ford", "Arthur" };

var count = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string s in strings) {
  if (count.ContainsKey(s)) {
    count[s]++;
  } else {
    count.Add(s, 1);
  }
}
foreach (var item in count) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
Zaphod : 2
Trillian : 1
Ford : 1
Arthur : 1
```

You can also do it using LINQ methods:

```
var count =
  strings
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .Select(
    g => new { Key = g.First(), Value = g.Count() }
  );
```

Comment: Nice code, but it doesn't answer the question that the op intended

Comment: @Yoni: If you know the exact intention of the OP, please post it somewhere in this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] comparisonList = {"a", "b" "c"};
 from s in comparisonList where comparisonList.Contains("b") select s;
```

Comment: I don't think LINQ is really necessary here.

Comment: @musicfreak: meh. @ash: it's been 4 years since LINQ released.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare, use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx).
If you to find a string in a list, use the Contains/Select method equivalent of the list type.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [String.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) static method as it let's you make everything explicit.  This is important as string comparisons can be notorious for subtle bugs.

For example:

```
// Populate with your strings
List<string> manyStrings = new List<string>();

string oneString="target string";

foreach(string current in manyStrings)
{
    // For a culture aware, safe comparison
    int compareResult=String.Compare(current,oneString,
                       StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    // OR
    // For a higher performance comparison
    int compareResult=String.Compare(current,oneString,
                       StringComparison.Ordinal);

    if (compareResult==0) 
    {
        // Strings are equal 

    }
}
```

If you actually want to just know if a string is a substring of another larger string, in the above loop you can use:

```
int indexPos=current.IndexOf(oneString,StringComparison.Ordinal); 

if (indexPos>=0)
{
    // oneString was found in current
}
```

Note that IndexOf accepts the same useful StringComparison enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

To find the strings in your list, which are in the list for multiple times, you could start putting those strings into a HashSet, and check for each one, whether it is already in this set.

For example, you could:

```
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string item in myList)
{
    if (hashSet.Contains(item)) 
    {
        // already in the list
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        // not seen yet, putting it into the hash set
        hashSet.Add(item);
    }
}
```