# How to use one string variable with multiple Conditional Or operators

Tags: c#, string, class

I'm trying to assign multiple abbreviations from a text box to a string variable but I can't figure out how. This is what I have so far.

```
string abbreviation = | "S" | "HC" | "HNC";
if (txtEmployeeType.Text != abbreviation)
```

It gives me an error under the first Or operator. What I'm trying to do is say that if someone doesn't type an S, HC, or HNC into the Employee Type text box, an error message box will show. But I'm just trying to figure out how to type the string variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a string with several different strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070013/comparing-a-string-with-several-different-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and .Contains

```
string[] abbreviatons = new string[] { "S", "HC", "HNC" };
if  (!abbreviations.Contains(txtEmployeeType.Text)) { /*do something*/ };
```

Answer (score 0):

To check that a `string` equals a `string` in a collection of `string`, do the following with LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var input = "abcd";
            string[] arguments = {"S", "HC", "HNC"};
            var isValid = IsValid(input, arguments);
        }

        private static bool IsValid(string text, params string[] arguments)
        {
            return arguments.Any(s => s == text);
        }
    }
}
```